How to find the percentage of a group that experienced a change in color.
Okay, let us give an example of what I am talking about. Let us say you have a collection of spheres, the amount doesn't matter, only percentages do.
Let us say they all possess a colour, they will be Red (49%), Blue (48%), and Green (3%).
Now let us say after a certain amount of time, they change colours, but not all of them. So you have Red (53%), Blue (42%) and Green (5%). Assume that the total amount of balls stays the same, the only change is in the colour of a subset of the balls.
For a more general solution, let us define them as variable R, B, G, and R', B', and G'.
How would you find what percentage of the whole changed colour? And it would help if you also can show what percent of each group changes. So, for example, if 80% remained the same colour as they were in their initial state, 20% would be considered to have changed from their initial state.
I want a general solution, displayed through solving the example I depicted. So that I can solve it for different scenarios.
If it is not solvable, please explain why it is not solvable.
Edit: For more clarity, as the percentages change, but the amount of balls does not, and members enter or leave the set of balls, a subset of the balls inherently must have moved between subgroups. For example, as R' is greater than R, some amount of B and G must have became red.
As B' is less than B, some amount of B must be lost, converted into R and G. And as G increases, you must take a certain amount from R and/or B.
I am asking for how one would find what percentage changes what group they are a member of, let us call that C, and what percent remained in the same group.
Assume the smallest possible percentage that could describe the given change.
I may be overcomplicating things. I am just asking for others to help partially to see if I am overcomplicating things, or if it is as complicated as I am making it out to be. Get a different eye on the problem and all.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

It may be instructive to consider a numerical example.  Suppose you initially have $r = 3$, $g = 2$, and $b = 5$ red, green, and blue balls, respectively.  Then:

$2$ red balls change to green
$1$ green ball changes to blue and $1$ green ball changes to red
$1$ blue ball changes to red

After this changing, what are the numbers of red, green, and blue balls?  It is the same as before.  Changing took place but if balls of the same color are indistinguishable, the effect of changing cancels out.
However, we can characterize a minimum number (hence proportion) of balls that change color.  Consider the same initial example as above except:

$1$ red ball changes to green
$2$ green balls change to blue
$2$ blue balls change to red, and $1$ blue ball changes to green.

This time, the number of balls of each color after the changes are $$r = 3 - 1 + 2 = 4, \quad g = 2 - 2 + 1 + 1 = 2, \quad b = 5 - 2 - 1 + 2 = 4.$$  Although $1 + 2 + 2 + 1 = 6$ balls (or $60\%$) switched colors, the ultimate effect of this changing is indistinguishable from a change that simply transfers $1$ blue ball to red:  $(3,2,5) \to (4,2,4)$.  In this respect, the minimum number of balls that effectively changed color is $1$, and the proportion of the whole that changed color would be $1/10 = 10\%$.
To extend this idea of "minimum changing" to your specific example, we need to calculate the minimum number of balls that change color when the initial state is $(49, 48, 3)$ and the final state is $(53, 42, 5)$.  There is an increase of $4$ in red, a decrease of $6$ in green, and an increase of $2$ in blue.  Hence the minimum change is $6\%$, attained by moving $4\%$ from green to red and $2\%$ from green to blue.
As there are only three colors, if $\Delta r = b_{\text{final}} - b_{\text{initial}}$, and similarly for $\Delta g, \Delta b$ are the respective changes from initial to final, then we must have $\Delta r + \Delta g + \Delta b = 0$ so long as the total number of balls remains constant.  The magnitude of the sum of all negative deltas must equal the magnitude of the sum of all positive deltas; moreover, both are equal to the minimum change.  But as stated above, this does not take into consideration changes that cancel each other out:  it is the minimum proportion of balls that must change color in order to transform from the initial to the final state.

Thanks. I was just overcomplicating things as this is ultimately a demographics question, so I was thinking in a lot more detail than the pure mathematics. Leading to me overcomplicating things. Such as trying to think of changes that would cancel each other out.

You can't know the answer without more information.  To see this, assume you have two colors, red and blue, each of which have been applied to half of the balls.  After the change, you still have the same two colors, each of which is still applied to half of the balls.
It could be that none of the balls have changed color.  It could be that every single ball has changed color.  Anything in between works as well, as long as the same number of balls of each original color change color.

There are three balls of unequal percentages. I have given the initial and final percentages in question for an example.

Please try to find the lowest possible percentage that could explain the change. For extra context that I added in the initial post.

The lowest percentage that could explain the change comes from keeping the maximum number of balls the same.  This is the minimum percentage for each color between the start and end.  So $49%$ of the balls stay red, $42%$ stay blue, and $3%$ stay green.  The other $6%$ change.  Those are blue balls that change to another color.

Yeah, it was indeed me overcomplicating things a lot. Thanks.
